# Проверка состояния promise в angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, request, promise

Есть сервис который делает запрос через `$http` , в обработке запроса (неважно `resolve` или `reject`) , я возвращаю какие то данные через `return`, в итоге сервис возвращает `promise`, как (допустим в контроллере , где я вызвал этот сервис) проверить на запросе был `resolve` или `reject`?

Пример сервиса:

```
return $http(option)
                .then(onResolve,onReject);
```

Пример вызова сервиса:

```
reguestService({
                url: `someUrl`,
                method: 'get',
            }).then(function (response) {
                // Как тут узнать был ли запрос успешным или нет ?
            });
```

Comment: ты же сам написал: `return $http(option)
                .then(onResolve,onReject);`

Answer (score 0):

У вас должно быть две функции в **then**. Первая - запрос прошёл успешно, вторая - с ошибкой.

```
return $http.get(options)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return error;
  })
```